# Best statistical method for analysing a single clubs football (soccer) results

Tags: time-series, games

Best statistical method for analysing a single clubs football (soccer) results?

I have every result for over 100 years in date order. Is there a recognised or recommended method for analysing results, making some sort of coefficient to help in predicting results or at least showing +/- progress based on each result.

apologies for the noob

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information. What do you want to analyze? What data (exactly) do you have? Right now, you are asking the technical equivalent of "is there some standard way of winning at soccer?"

Comment: i have every result, w,l,d, goals for, goals against and the opponent. is there a way of building a coefficient similar to euroclubindex.com to work out how likely a team is to win given home advantage, previous overall history, previous history versus that particular opposition.

Comment: This will likely require GAMM (Generalized Additive Mixed Models), which sort of conflicts with your self-proclaimed noob-status :-( No easy solutions there, I'm afraid. Even then: you are missing vast quantities of information still, so I would doubt the predictive ability of this kind of model for individual games (though they may perform OK on average).

Comment: @NickSabbe I have a similar problem, could you recommend some literature on topic of Generalized Addictive Mixed Models (I'm not a math noob).

Comment: @enedene The models are not addictive they are additive.  A Freudianslip maybe?

Comment: It strikes me that old data on teams that played 100 years ago would have no relevance with regard to future play.  Much of that old data may be useless or even counterproductive.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The name is the same, the game totally different. I wouldn't use data from 1980, let alone 100 years ago. Also the rules are different (for example you can't waste time by constantly returning the ball to goalkeeper hands) as well as the point system (2 points for a win, now it's 3) which makes a draw much less attractive outcome. As for additive/addictive, I do make such mistakes occasionally, unfortunately I can't edit the comment.

Comment: Cheers for the recent comments on this thread. I have still not found a suitable methodology that is reliable.

Comment: When i used to do archery i used to record my score out of the maxmium possible and compare it to my previous average across all tournaments, i then added 3 points if i shot above my average or 1 point for atleast having a go. the average changed for each shoot and i quickly found i was slowly improving over time. so much so i could accurately predict how well i would do in a tournament +/- 5 points out of a maximum of 256-964. nothing like this for football though!